# FFMPEG generate audio based on video motion

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have an IP camera with video only. I'd like to generate audio to go along with the video. The audio volume would be determined by the amount of motion in the scene.

Sine wave generation:
https://superuser.com/a/724462

'Scene' [0,1] attribute in select filter:
https://superuser.com/a/1029175

Is there any way to combine these together? Save the attribute from one filter to be used later?