# reducing noise in scene select logic in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, motion-detection

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1029175/121080) I am using this command to extract only components of a (mostly unchanging) video feed which have motion in them:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.0001),setpts=N/(25*TB)" output.mp4
```

However, I have found that under certain (e.g. lower) lighting conditions I start seeing a lot of frame capture despite nothing apparently happening in the video.  Under these conditions there does seem to be a lot of noise, which I assume is making the total amount of change exceed the threshold.  Indeed, if I double the threshold most of this goes away - but still not all of it.  However, if I bump up the threshold more, I will start missing actual small motion that I don't want to miss.

My thought was that if the filter first did something to reduce the amount of noise in the scene, perhaps some kind of slight blurring at a resolution of 2-3 pixels, this would eliminate the spurious motion detection and I could detect actual motion on a smaller scale.  I see some options to blur, but the documentation on the [selection filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) doesn't talk about how to use them indirectly, i.e. I don't want the actual output affected, only the scene detection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an actual de-noising filter before select in your filter chain?

Something like `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "vaguedenoiser=PARAMS,select=gt(scene\,0.0001),setpts=N/(25*TB)" output.mp4`?

Do a search for `denoise` at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vaguedenoiser for a few others.

Comment: would that propogate the filtered frames to the output, or limit it to the scene selecter?

Comment: well so far i have played around with hard, soft and garrote methods, using strengths from 2 to 10 on a reduced light scene that is capturing 5fps with no movement.  the only parameter that has helped at all is threshold=2, garrote which reduced it to 4fps.  Not much of an improvement...

Comment: `unsharp=9:9:-2:9:9:-2` reduces fps from 5 to 3, although it also is blurring the output